# How to insert variable into xpath expression statement C#?

Tags: c#, xpath, expression

I'm new to Xpath expression and I have some questions to ask.

I will like to insert the string selectedcountry into my xpath expression so I tried coding like this, `//a[contains(@href, "+selectedCountry+")]/text()` but got back the incorrect data that I wanted.

The selectedCountry string from the session is retrieved from the user so I'm sure that the value inside is correct.

When i change to `//a[contains(@href," "+selectedCountry+" ")]/text()`,the following error appears:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Situation 1

```
string selectedCountry = Session["SelectedCountry"].ToString();

HtmlNode[] newnode = doc3.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href,'china')]/text()").ToArray();
```

Result :

> China backs joint energy development with Philippines in disputed sea
>   China urges ASEAN to reject outside interference Panama opens embassy
>   in China after cutting Taiwan ties Botswana confirms Dalai Lama visit
>   despite China anger

Situation 2

```
string selectedCountry = Session["SelectedCountry"].ToString();

HtmlNode[] newnode = doc3.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href,"+selectedCountry+")]/text()").ToArray();
```

Result :

> Jump to Main                     To Home                    Asia
>   PacificSingaporeWorldCNA
>   InsiderBusinessSportLifestyleTechnologyHealthCommentaryCatch-up TV

Comment: When i change to "//a[contains(@href," "+selectedCountry+" ")]/text()",the error appears.

What's the actual line of C# that that appears in? Because I don't see how it even compiles.

Answer (score 0):

If `"//a[contains(@href, 'china')]/text()"` works but `"//a[contains(@href, "+selectedCountry+")]/text()"` does not, ensure that `selectedCountry` contains `'china'` including the apostrophes

If it doesn't contain the apostrophes, either add them to the variable or add them to the string:

```
"//a[contains(@href, '"+selectedCountry+"')]/text()"
```